# Documenting Javascript Parameters in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I am trying to document a javascript function in Visual Studio 2013. The particular function has a parameter of type jQuery, but IntelliSense is not picking up on the type, even though I have the vsdoc.js file referenced earlier in the file. Here is my code:

Early in file

```
/// <reference path="path_to_vsdoc/jquery-1.10.2-vsdoc.js" />
```

Later

```
/// <param name="dep" type="jQuery">The dependent element as a jQuery selector.</param>
function myfunction(dep) { ... }
```

When I type `dep.` VS gives me a message "IntelliSense was unable to determine an accurate completion list for this expression. The provided list contains all identifiers in the file. What I'm wondering is whether I can use types defined in my referenced files (i.e. jquery-1.10.2-vsdoc.js). "jQuery" is used as a type in the vsdoc file.

Thanks for the help!

Edit:

Turns out I'm silly and you have to put your function documentation inside the function.

Comment: You should take your edit and make it into an answer, with a snippet of code to show how it works.  That will be more clear and useful to anyone who has the same issue in the future.